# User number input to Grab Arrays in "Quotes" and print

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, forms, user-input

I have a very simple webpage which is a resume website. I would like to have something that will take the user input and generate a response based on the array in "quotes". The program would ask for up to 5 job discriptions and list only the amount the user inputs.

Like, 2 inputed would be "Cleaning" "Register" and 3 would be "Cleaning" "Register" "Customer Service"

It would be something like this: User inputs number >Clicks a button >Program takes only the number of arrays asked for up to five >Outputs the "names" in the arrays for however many asked for.

**This is what I have so far but have no idea how to go from here!**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var duties = ["Inventory", "Box Office Sales", " Cleaning Duties", " Opening and Closing", " Daily Paperwork "]
  duties.sort();
  var i;
  var text = "";

  for (i = 0; i < duties.length; i++) {
    text += duties[i] + "<br/>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = duties;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">View Job Duties</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

  <form action="demo_form.asp">
    Amount of job duties:
    <input type="text" name="jduties">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: this is not a tutorial site, unfortunately... give it a go through tutorials (plenty of them out there, plus loads of responses to parts of what you want on here too), and give us exact code if you're stuck, we'll be happy to help ;)

Comment: I added code but I don't know where to start. Do you know where I can get help with this if I am unable to do it here?

Comment: start by searching for "create a form in html", avoid w3schools as they're often incorrect, maybe this one will get you started (but like i said, there are plenty of such articles on the net): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/My_first_HTML_form